# WebRTC over internet/heroku not working (video, audio streaming)

Tags: javascript, heroku, webrtc, video-streaming

I am making a WebRTC video chat app basically. You can create a room, and the user can join in using the provided 6-digit code. In the room, you have the video chat, shared notepad, chat, screenshare and other tiny details. The app works great locally (when i open up 2 browser tabs and communicate over them), but after i finished up the MVP and deployed it to heroku I found out no one can connect to me. What happens is that the guest joins the room, his local video and mine (hosts) are working, but we cannot see each other and the host gets the alert that the guest left the conversation (guest leave handler which is called when ice candidate state is changed). I have tried implementing a TURN server, but no help. This is the code snippet that gets called when the user joins. (I'm getting the ice candidate from the mongoDB database):

```
const iceConfiguration = { }
iceConfiguration.iceServers = [];
//turn server
iceConfiguration.iceServers.push({
    url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    credential: 'muazkh',
    username: 'webrtc@live.com'
},)
//stun  server
iceConfiguration.iceServers.push({
                urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
            })    
let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration.iceServers)
async function start(){
  localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
  remoteStream = new MediaStream()
  localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
  });

  peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
    console.log(event.streams[0])
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
  };

  webcamVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
  webcamVideo.muted = true

  peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = async function() {
    if(peerConnection.iceConnectionState == 'disconnected') {
        if (username == host){
          alert("guest left")
          await fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/removeGuest`, {method: "PUT"})
          peerConnection.close()
          peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration.iceServers)
          start()
        }else{
          handleHostDisconnect()
        }
    }
  }
  if (username === host){
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = () =>  {
      console.log("New ice candidate")
    }

    const sendChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel("sendChannel");

    sendChannel.onopen = () => canSendMessages = true;
    sendChannel.onclose = () => console.log("closed!!!!!!");

    const offerDescription = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      hostOffer: JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription.toJSON())
    })
    fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/hostOffer`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body
    })
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const interval = setInterval(async ()=>{
      const res = await fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/get`, {
        "signal": controller.signal
      })
      const data = await res.json()
      if (data.guestAnswer){
        controller.abort()
        clearInterval(interval)
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(data.guestAnswer))
      }
    }, 2500)
  }
//GUEST JOINING
  else{
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = async () =>{
        console.log("JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription)")
        const body = JSON.stringify({
          guestAnswer: JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription)
        })
        await fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/guestAnswer`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body
        })
    }

    peerConnection.ondatachannel = (ev) =>{
        const receiveChannel = ev.channel
        receiveChannel.onopen = () => canSendMessages = true;
        receiveChannel.onclose = () => console.log("closed!!!!!!");
        peerConnection.channel = receiveChannel;

    }
    const res = await fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/get`)
    const interview = await res.json()
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(interview.hostOffer))

    const localDesc = await peerConnection.createAnswer()
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(localDesc)
    otherNameLabel.textContent = interview.host
    otherUser = interview.host 
  }

}
```

Sorry if the code is a little confusing, I tried to remove as many irrelevant lines as possible.
Don't be confused by the "interview" label, its a session, bacause the web app is meant to be for simplifying coding interviews.
Stack: Node.js, MongoDB, Express, hbs

Answer (score 0):

The TURN credentials you are using aren't valid. This can be confirmed using  the [trickle-ice](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) test page. If the credentials worked you would get a relay candidate.

You can either run your own TURN server, or pay for a hosted one.

You will have a greater connectivity success rate if you publish candidates from both sides. Right now you only have a `onicecandidate` when `if (username !== host)`

Comment: Okay, I will try to spin up a TURN server on my Raspberry PI and tell you if that worked. Dont know what you meant in that last paragraph though, I am saving the hosts offer in MongoDB aswell. fetch(`/session/${interviewId}/hostOffer`)

Comment: The TURN server needs to be on a world routable IP unfortunately. If two WebRTC PeerConnections can't establish direct connectivity it gives them something to route through. https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#turn explains a little bit more.

Comment: Shouldn't port forwarding do the job?